# Spring-boot Web sending echo response, every other request

Tags: rest, spring-boot, load-balancing

We have spring-boot Rest service working for fine for last couple of month. We are packaging default jar file with embedded tomcat engine. New problem has started, where it echo back every other request.

Request 1 Verb POST- get valid response back

request 2 POST- response is echo of request 2!

Request 3 POST- get valid response

Request 4 POST - gets echo....

How to resolve this issue?

we tried rebuilding jar, deploying to multiple machine, with and without hardware load balancer.

Comment: What is your runtime environment? I mean, where do you run your application?

Comment: Really, there's not enough information here to solve your problem.  It certainly sounds like a load balancing round-robin issue, but short of posting your microservice, load balance solution and version, and all your configuration, I'm not sure how much help people can be! Get more specific, and you might get more help.

Comment: Check your `@Configuration` classes and `@Bean` methods as well, if there is any logging configs there.